# Arrastrar un elemento con aumento de enteros en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, matemáticas

Estoy dibujando un polígono como se hace en geogebra y calculo la distancia entre cada punto (los vértices del polígono), los puntos son arrastrables.

Por lo que actualmente uso los pixeles del teléfono para manejar mi plano cartesiano imaginario y así poder calcular la distancia entre dos puntos.

El código siguiente corresponde a un punto posicionado en un Stack :

```
    Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          position = Offset(
              position.dx + details.delta.dx, position.dy + details.delta.dy);
```

Al arrastrar un punto se actualiza la posición sumando la posición actual más `details.delta.dx`.

El problema es que `details.delta.dx` actualiza la posición con muchos decimales, por lo que al calcular la distancia aparece con muchos decimales y deseo una medida exacta.

Esto ocurre al arrastrar el punto.

**¿Hay alguna forma de limitar que solo vaya aumentando por enteros al arrastrar?**

Ya he tratado con hacer un `round` a `details.delta.dx`, sin embargo, eso no resuelve el problema.

Comment: Puedes hacer un cast del número a Int. Supongo que actualmente tu número sera un double. Cuando lo vayas a mostar puedes hacer: double.toInt(). O, una mejor opción podría ser usar double.ToStringAtFixed(X), si no recuerdo mal ese era el nombre. Ese método transforma el número en String con la cantidad de decimales pasados al parámetro del método.